# Does the part tag provide any value?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I just came across a question tagged [part](/questions/tagged/part).  The Wiki entry for 'part' says:

> A part of text, file, data structure, buffer, code, library, API or the like (add more tags to clarify).

If the tag is not capable of standing on its own, I wonder if it really provides any value?  For my money, it does not and it should be burninated.

Comment: It doesn't stand on its own or serve to provide more specificity to support other tags. I'm surprised someone took the time to write that description.

Comment: @BilltheLizard free rep?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took the upvotes as an indication that [part](/questions/tagged/part) should be eliminated.

There are now (currently) no questions tagged [part](/questions/tagged/part).